# How to sum the value in a key/value list of tuples that has duplicates key?

Tags: haskell

Consider the exemple:

```
[("AAA",2),("BBB",5),("AAA",12),("CCC",45),("BBB",21)]
```

And I want to combine the tuples containing the same key (String) by adding the values and result would be like this:

```
[("AAA",14),("BBB",26),("CCC",45)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are your problems?

Comment: `import Data.Map; toDescList (fromListWith (+) yourTuplesList)`